# C: copying array in function by using pointers gave unusual result, why did it half work?

Tags: arrays, c, void-pointers, function-definition, pointer-arithmetic

So I don't want to make a function for every data type, I would like to be able to just use pointers to fix the problem. Tried the idea with a function for copying an array. I didn't get the result i expected or wanted, even if it had just gone entirely wrong with the new_arr not changing at all i would be ok this isn't it. but it gave me hope.

```
void *copy_array(const void *arr[], const void *new_arr[], size_t arr_len, size_t type_size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_len ; ++i) {
        *(new_arr + (i * type_size)) = *(arr + (i * type_size));
    }
}

void print_int_array(int * array, int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        printf("\nelement %d = %d", i, array[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr[ARRAY_LENGTH]     = {12, 3,4};
    int new_arr[ARRAY_LENGTH] = {0, 0, 0};

    print_int_array(arr, ARRAY_LENGTH);
    print_int_array(new_arr, ARRAY_LENGTH);

    copy_array(&arr, &new_arr, ARRAY_LENGTH, sizeof(new_arr[0]));

    print_int_array(arr, ARRAY_LENGTH);
    print_int_array(new_arr, ARRAY_LENGTH);
    return 0;
}
```

Console returns this for some reason, it gets the 12 and the 3 by why not the 4?

```
element 0 = 12
element 1 = 3
element 2 = 4
element 0 = 0
element 1 = 0
element 2 = 0
element 0 = 12
element 1 = 3
element 2 = 4
element 0 = 12
element 1 = 3
element 2 = 0
```

Comment: copy_array should return something, probably new_arr or change the return type to void.  What is ARRAY_LINE?  Please update your code to be a [mre].  &arr and &new_arr is a int (*)[3] but caller expects void *[].

Comment: Your function expects arrays of pointers to void, but you are trying to feed it pointers to length 3 arrays of int - not even of pointers to some type. Perhaps you want your function to take parameters of void * instead of void ** (i.e. void *[] )

Comment: Do you compile with warnings enabled? I'm halfway sure a compiler could give you a hint or two.

Comment: Your function doesn't take array parameters. In C, a parameter declared array is converted to pointer; `void *foo[]` means the same thing as `void **foo`, as a parameter. If you specify a size, it still has to be valid: `void *foo[-1]` is a constraint violation, even though after the array conversion, `void **` has no concept of array size.

Comment: Since you seem to want to do byte-wise arithmetic on the pointers with your own computed scaling, you want `unsigned char *param` pointers. In GCC `void *param` will work; GCC allows byte-scaled arithmetic on void pointers as a language extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared a function

```
void *copy_array(const void *arr[], const void *new_arr[], size_t arr_len, size_t type_size) {
```

where the both first parameters have the qualifier `const`. So the function declaration is incorrect.

Instead it would be better to declare the first parameter of the function `print_int_array` with the qualifier `const` and the second parameter as having the type `size_t`

```
void print_int_array( const int * array, size_t length) {
```

On the other hand, the expressions

```
*(new_arr + (i * type_size))
```

and

```
*(arr + (i * type_size))
```

have pointer types. Their sizes can be greater than the size of an object of the type int. For example `sizeof( void * )` can be equal to `8` while `sizeof( int )` can be equal to `4`.

Thus the function can invoke undefined behavior.

Apart from that the function has a non-void return type but returns nothing.

Also there is no great sense to call the function passing pointers to arrays like

```
copy_array(&arr, &new_arr, ARRAY_LENGTH, sizeof(new_arr[0]));
```

where each expression has the type `int( * )[3]`.

The function can be defined the following way as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void copy_array( void *new_arr, const void *arr, size_t arr_len, size_t type_size ) 
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr_len; i++)
    {
        memcpy( new_arr, arr, type_size );
        new_arr = ( char * )new_arr + type_size;
        arr = ( const char * )arr + type_size;
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    enum { ARRAY_LENGTH = 3 };
    int arr[ARRAY_LENGTH] = { 12, 3,4 };
    int new_arr[ARRAY_LENGTH] = { 0, 0, 0 };

    printf( "arr    : " );
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", arr[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    printf( "new_arr: " );
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", new_arr[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    putchar( '\n' );

    copy_array( new_arr, arr, ARRAY_LENGTH, sizeof( int ) );

    printf( "arr    : " );
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", arr[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    printf( "new_arr: " );
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", new_arr[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
arr    : 12 3 4
new_arr: 0 0 0

arr    : 12 3 4
new_arr: 12 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is what i wanted to do which is basicly memcpy. The arrays get converted to char arrays which is only 1 byte, so every byte gets copied from the size of the original array.

```c
void copy_array(void *arr, void *new_arr, size_t arr_size) {
    char *char_new_arr = (char *) new_arr;
    char *char_arr     = (char *) arr;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; ++i) {
        char_new_arr[i] = char_arr[i];
    }
}
```